# "Addition function" that works for both perm and det simultaneously?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, algebraic-complexity, arithmetic-circuits, permanent, determinant

For $f = (f_n)$ a family of polynomials where $f_n$ is a polynomial in $n^2$ variables (which we can think of as the entries of an $n \times n$ matrix), say a function $S(A,B)$ is an addition function for $f$ if for all square matrices $A,B$, $f(S(A,B)) = f(A) + f(B)$.

Since both the determinant [https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jco.2006.09.006] and the permanent [https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/51348/129] are linearly closed families, they both have addition functions.

If instead of addition functions, we ask for product functions, there is a *single* construction that works for both det and perm, namely the block-diagonal direct sum of matrices: $\det(A \oplus B) = \det(A)\det(B)$ and $perm(A \oplus B)=perm(A)perm(B)$.

> Is there a single function $S(A,B)$ that is an addition function for both det and perm?

I suppose in principle $S$ could depend on the sizes of $A,B$, but it'd be even nicer if it were "uniform" in a similar sense to how the direct sum is uniform. I leave this a bit vague as there are many ways the direct sum construction is uniform, and I'm not sure I have a preference.

Edit: As pointed out by @GeoffreyIrving in the comments, the construction $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ y & x \end{bmatrix}$ works, where $x+y=perm(A) +perm(B)$ and $x-y=det(A) +det(B)$. But this requires computing det and perm in the first place. So let's say at the very least I'd want a construction with poly-size formulas (hence, we think, easier than det). And really what I want is a projection in Valiant's sense, since all the constructions in the OQ above are of that form. Meaning that each entry of S(A, B) should be either a constant or an entry of A or B.

Comment: Is true that for any $d, p \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a $2 \times 2$ matrix with determinant $d$ and permanent $p$?  If so, I think the answer is yes, but not necessarily in an interesting way.

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving: yes. Let x, y be such that x+y=p and x-y=d. Then the matrix ((1,1),(y,x)) does it (this works over any field, which is nice because ideally I'd want the construction over an arbitrary field). Can you say more?

Comment: Well, as stated one can just compute the determinants and permanents and the map to the appropriate $2 \times 2$ matrix.  But presumably you want a tractability constraint?

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving Oh, uh, yeah. Or at least that the construction itself should not use perm or det. Maybe I want S to be a projection (in Valiant's sense).  I'll have to think about that and update the question.