# On perm+1 and det+1

Tags: planar-graphs, permanent, bipartite-graphs, determinant, spanning-tree

Given a balanced bipartite graph G and a planar graph H. We do not know the number of perfect matchings in G and we do not know the number of spanning trees in H. But assume they are at least 3 both.

1.Can we construct in P, a balanced bipartite graph G', whose number of perfect matchings is one more than that for G?

We can ask same question as above with any $\#PE$ problem ($\#P$ problems with decision version in $P$)

2.Can we construct in L, a planar graph H', whose number of spanning trees is one more than that for H?

Comment: If G itself is a perfect matching, then it only has 1 perfect matching. If H is a tree, it's planar but has only one spanning tree. Also, if a planar graph is disconnected it might have 0 spanning trees. Not crucial to the question itself, but did you mean to have some other assumptions or other conclusion in your first paragraph?

Comment: I am assuming the count is at least 2.

Comment: Okay, I guess that's a fine assumption. But now I'm curious: why do you want to assume they are at least 2?

Comment: Related: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/51348/129. (But that explicitly doesn't answer this question, as the construction there will produce a graph whose *weighted* perfect matchings add up to perm+1, rather than unweighted.)

Comment: Just for genericity.. there are no graphs with #spanning trees =2