# On mod $2^i$ $+$-reducibility of permanent

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, permanent

Suppose we have two bipartite graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ with perfect matching count $P_1$ and $P_2$ respectively then their disjoint union gives a bipartite graph with perfect matching $P_1P_2$.

> Is there a graph construction in polynomial time to get a bipartite graph from  $G_1$ and $G_2$ with perfect matching count mod $2^i$ exactly $(P_1+P_2)\bmod2^i$ where $i=\Omega(n)$ is allowed?

Related: [Is Permanent $+$-reducible?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/38772/is-permanent-reducible)